Titlesec error just after usepackage command
I want to give headers of sections a color.
After I have included titlesec.sty and an error message pops-up.
I have not applied yet any titlesec command. The file titlesec.sty line 1635 does look OK as far as I can see. Is there a conflict in the order or in relation to apa7? Is there a work around?
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty:1635: Argume
nt of \subparagraph has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1635 \ttl@extract\subparagraph
                                
? 

The code is
\documentclass[man, donotrepeattitle, floatsintext, 12pt, a4paper]{apa7}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{color,soul}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage[american]{varioref}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 
  \usepackage{titlesec}

% the title commands 
\title{working title\\

}

\shorttitle{working}
\authorsnames{Employee}
\authorsaffiliations{Educational Sciences {,} Summer}

\duedate{Aug-2025}

\authornote{Student number: \\
E-mail address: \\
Course code and name: \\
Supervisor: assistent prof. \\
Number of words: t.b.s\\
Date: 01-08-2025
}


\abstract{\lipsum[1][1-1]\\
}


% section numbering
\setcounter {secnumdepth}{4}

\definecolor{TEAL}{RGB}{0, 139, 139}
% commands for section color
\newcommand{\hcol}[1]{{\color{TEAL}#1}}
 

% change title page headers t0 place the OU logo
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{% <<<<<<<<<<<< added
    \lhead{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{OUlogo.png}}% your logo here <<<
    \rhead{} %\rhead{\thepage}% for page-nr 1
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{\hcol{Introduction} }
\subsection{\hcol{SUBSECTION}}

\end{document}


clearly titlesec is not compatible with apa7, so do not use it.

If you're required to use apa7, then don't change anything the class sets up. If you're not required to use apa7, keep it at arm's distance.

titlesec is not compatible with your class. If you want to change the sectioning commands, copy the definitions from the class and adapt them:
\documentclass[man, donotrepeattitle, floatsintext, 12pt, a4paper]{apa7}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\shorttitle{working}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {\b@level@one@skip}{\e@level@one@skip}%
    {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{red}}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {\b@level@two@skip}{\e@level@two@skip}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{blue}}}    
\makeatother    
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}


